# NestJs server does not start

Tags: node.js, api, websocket, nestjs, nrwl

when I run the start command in NestJs I got no error but a text repeats one after the other and won't let the server start.

This is the text

```
Debugger listening on ws://localhost:9229/d85c77f4-d1c6-4b88-a91a-1905252c8913
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
chunk (runtime: main) main.js (main) 30.5 KiB [entry]
webpack compiled successfully (bdb03efc0de1a987)
No issues found.
```

[image]